# Jmockit @Mocked return empty object on lombok @builder

Tags: jmockit, lombok

I am using Jmockit for my Junit test.

When I'm testing a function which uses lombok's builder.build(), it returns an instance with empty values.

I've also tried to use @Injectable and @Capturing, both gave me the same result.

```
@Test
public void test_updateStatusFromResponse_success_payment_result(@Mocked MyObject myObject) {
    myClass.myFunction("paraA","paraB");
}

public class myClass{
    public void myFunction(String paraA, String paraB){
        MyObject myObject = MyObject.builder.
                                     StringA(paraA).
                                     StringB(paraB).
                                     build();
        //myObject's both StringA and StringB is null
    }
}

@Builder
@Getter
public class MyObject {
    private final String StringA;
    private final String StringB;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little lost, you're mocking Order class, but Order class doesn't appear anywhere in the code except for the @Mocked part. Second, I've never seen something like 'public class myClass(String paraA, String paraB)' is it some kind of functionality I don't know or did you want to put the params on myFunction()?

Comment: Sorry for my copy and paste mistake, I have updated the code

Comment: I'd say the problem is that you're mocking MyObject, so ALL of its methods get mocked (so they won't do anything) including the setters, getters and quite sure the builder too (although I've never used lombok).

You may want to try partial mocking for this (http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#partial).

Comment: It is also unclear what you are trying to test here. Without any assertions or further explanation, it's hard to suggest anything beyond @Alfergon's "try partial mocking" suggestion. But that may not be the right approach; can you clarify what you are expecting?